# postfix welcome message smtpd_banner

Tags: postfix, smtpd

I would like to greet the remote client showing his IP.

For example:

> "mysite.com ESMTP Hello xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx your actions will be logged"

I have this...

> smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP Hello $client_address your actions will be logged

But `$client_address` is not showing the remote client IP. What variable should I use in order to show the client IP? how can I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Hmm, does ${client_address} work?

Comment: ${client_address} doesn't work either :/

Comment: You can do this with exim smtp_banner = "$smtp_active_hostname, ESMTP Hello $sender_host_address your actions will be logged"

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, in the smtpd_banner you can use only 2 variables - $myhostname and $mail_name

Comment: Well.. unless you hack the postfix code and recompile it yourself..

Comment: and $mail_version